# Get child nodes of namespaced node simplexml php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

My XML :

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:admin="http://webns.net/mvcb/" xmlns:doap="http://usefulinc.com/ns/doap#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/" xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
<rdf:Description rdf:about="">
    <admin:generatorAgent rdf:resource="http://purl.org/NET/erdf/extract"/>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about=""/>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="#oryx_9A42131E-B88E-41D6-A3C4-A681F2BC93F7">
    <type xmlns="http://oryx-editor.org/">Collapsed</type>

</rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

I need all the node values inside tag `rdf:Description`

Attempt:

1) Using children function-

I Initialize $rootelement as SimpleXML object :

```
foreach ($rootelement->children("rdf",TRUE)->Description as $element) {
    var_dump($element->type); //This doesnt work
    var_dump((string)$element->type); //Even this doesnt work
}
```

2) Using xpath queries -

```
foreach($rootelement->xpath('//rdf:Description') as $event) {
    var_dump($event->xpath('rdf:type'));//Not working
    var_dump($event->xpath('type'));//Still not working
}
```

Any Idea how can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you call 'node values' ?

Comment: So - https://eval.in/598827 you can get list of Description items. But i don't understand what's next

Comment: By Node values I mean the child nodes of the namespace node `rdf:Description`

Comment: I get it, the The 'type' is available but how can I access that?

Comment: https://eval.in/598844

Comment: Awesome. But how can I access the attribute of `rdf:Description`? I guess this method works only to get child info. Correct me If I'm wrong.

Comment: https://eval.in/598847

Comment: You're awesome. Thanks.